# Using word wrap with mc

Tags: editors, mc

According to the man page for `mc`, the internal editor (`mc -e`) has a word wrap option. How can I turn this on? I have found settings in "Options" --> "General", however, this seems to only change text as it is typed in, and I cannot determine how to apply word wrap to text which has already been typed.

Comment: It seems more like a bug you should report to the developers. BTW, you can call the binary `mcedit` directly, and have a look at `man mcedit` instead.

Comment: To me it seems intentional. Neither changing the tab handling will replace all tabs in the existing text. Try the **External formatter** command from the Format or Command menu (depends on `mc` version) instead. That executes the `~/.mc/cedit/edit.indent.rc` script. Or add a command to the User menu, to execute `fold` or `fmt` on a selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mcedit's (or mc -e) word wrap is not like a regular word wrap in an editor. It is not just showing you a file with long lines wrapped so you can see the lines. Instead it actually and effectively creates new lines in your text file. It puts 'new-line' at the end of the lines and it alters your file.

As a proof, wrtie a couple of long lines in a file, than enable word wrap and let it wrap another couple or so lines. Save the file and than do a 'cat' of the file. You will see that it displays the lines wrapped.